# NC file having different groups - need to extract selected one variable from all the groups

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

[image: the details in ine group is shown in the pic - 2][[image: Here I have attached details of 1 nc file showing the list of groups in it1]

I wanted to know how one can read nc file containg different groups in loop (in pic shown list of different groups, and another pic shows the details from one group, I need to take the mean of albedo for all the groups of each NC file. I tried using xarray.open_datasets but it returns an empty file.. maybe due to variables are stored in groups? I have attached my sample .nc file, I have around ~300 such nc file and from each file, i need to take one variable under all the groups and store in csv file.

I tried but it gives an empty array.

I tried using xr.open_dataset to open the nc file but it returns empty file, may data is there in each group within that nc file

```
dirname='C:/Data1'

lst = []

for k in os.listdir(dirname):
    if k.endswith('.nc'):
        lst.append(k)

lst.sort()
print (lst)

for i in lst:
        data = xr.open_dataset(os.path.join(dirname, i),engine='netcdf4')
        print(data)
```

Comment: You haven’t actually attached the sample data. Can you re-edit? Potentially this is just a very badly structured file and xarray is unable to parse the metadata

Comment: Hi @RobertWilson, I have attached the pic from details of my NC file. I have various groups in the 1 nc file like [0000], [0400] .. I need to take the mean of all the Albedo values from each group - like Albedo had 5 bands, so I need to take 5 values at given line and pixel position. if I succeed in extract mean from all the groups for 1 nc file, I will need to run a loop for all the NC file. Any help in this would be great.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead copy it in as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Your file likely does not have any variables at the root level, but may contain groups with variables in a nested hierarchy.

xarray cannot be used to open multi-group hierarchies or to list groups within a netCDF file, but it can open a specific group if you know it’s path.

To list the groups in the file, first open the file with the `netcdf4` library directly. See the [netCDF4 docs](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#groups-in-a-netcdf-file). Specifically, the `.groups` attribute on a `netCDF4.Dataset` object contains key-value pairs giving the group name and the `netCDF4.Group` object:

```py
>>> from netCDF4 import Dataset
>>> rootgrp = Dataset("test.nc", "r")
>>> print(rootgrp.groups)
{'forecasts': <class 'netCDF4.Group'>
group /forecasts:
    dimensions(sizes): 
    variables(dimensions): 
    groups: , 'analyses': <class 'netCDF4.Group'>
group /analyses:
    dimensions(sizes): 
    variables(dimensions): 
    groups: }
```

Note that these groups can themselves have groups, so you may need to recursively explore the hierarchy to find all variables. The docs linked above contain an example showing how you might do this:

```py
>>> def walktree(top):
...     yield top.groups.values()
...     for value in top.groups.values():
...         yield from walktree(value)

>>> for children in walktree(rootgrp):
...     for child in children:
...         print(child)
<class 'netCDF4.Group'>
group /forecasts:
    dimensions(sizes): 
    variables(dimensions): 
    groups: model1, model2
<class 'netCDF4.Group'>
group /analyses:
    dimensions(sizes): 
    variables(dimensions): 
    groups: 
<class 'netCDF4.Group'>
group /forecasts/model1:
    dimensions(sizes): 
    variables(dimensions): 
    groups: 
<class 'netCDF4.Group'>
group /forecasts/model2:
    dimensions(sizes): 
    variables(dimensions): 
    groups:
```

Once you have the group path, you can read the group using [`xr.open_dataset`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html) by passing the `group` keyword argument, e.g.:

```py
ds = xr.open_dataset(
    "test.nc", group="/forecasts/model2"
)
```

See the xarray docs on [reading and writing data: netCDF](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#netcdf) for more info and examples.

You can also pass the group argument to [`xr.open_mfdataset`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html) to open the same group from many files:

```py
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(
    ["test1.nc", "test2.nc"],
    combine="nested",
    group="/forecasts/model2",
)
```

Work is currently underway to enable reading tree-like data structures like this. You can try out a prototype implementation with the [`xarray-datatree`](https://github.com/xarray-contrib/datatree) python package.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDelgado, thanks for your code, however my file structure is bit different. I have added the pics for my data structure and group details. I have attached the pic from details of my NC file. I have various groups in the 1 nc file like [0000], [0400] .. I need to take the mean of all the Albedo values from each group - like Albedo had 5 bands, so I need to take 5 values at given line and pixel position. if I succeed in extract mean from all the groups for 1 nc file, I will need to run a loop for all the NC file. Any help in this would be great.

Comment: You can read in each group one at a time. You cannot read in multiple groups with a single command. So just read in each group with a separate read command